# Changing adjustment pot in DC-DC converter

Tags: resistors, resistance, boost, module

I have a DC-DC boost converter module with 390 V output. Its output voltage is adjustable using its 50 kohm multi-turn preset pot.

[image]

[image]

The problem for me is this multi-turn preset pot takes too many turns to change resistance. I replaced it with a 50 kohm single-turn pot.

[image]

That works great except it's too fast in changing the value so I want to slow it down a little bit.

Will it be OK to change the 50 kohm pot to 100 kohm and will that slow down the value changing?

**Update**

I tried to find a datasheet or schematic but this is the only schematic i found

[image]

Comment: Do you have schematics of the DC-DC module? Need to know what resistance is used to divide feedback voltage in serial to the POT.

Comment: Choose a multiturn pot that has fewer turns.

Comment: @tito I've updated my answer based on now having at least a partial schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How fast the voltage changes will depend on the voltage range the pot works over. Changing the pot to a different value will affect that range. A higher value pot will increase the range, so a small change in position will affect the voltage more, a lower value will limit the range but you'll get less change for the same rotation.

If you want to slow down the speed you could go with a multi-turn pot that has less turns than the original, you can get them with different amounts of turns, common ones are 3, 5, 10, 15 and 20 turns. You can also get ones with turn counting knobs, these make it easier to adjust them.

A chassis mount multi-turn pot will be easier to turn than the original trim pot, if only because you don't need a screwdriver, so there's an option.

Another option is gearing, you can get knobs that will increase the number of turns it takes for a single turn pot.

**Addendum:**
Now that you've added a partial schematic we can see what's going on better.

They're using the pot as a rheostat (a two terminal variable resistor as opposed to a 3 terminal one), one end and the wiper are connected. This is in a voltage divider, 3 x 300k on top, the 50k pot and 5.6k in the bottom. Knowing that ratio and the reference voltage we can get an idea of the output voltage.

With the pot at one extreme it will be 0\$\Omega\$ and the ratio will be:
$$
\frac{5.6K + 0\Omega}{3\times300k + 5.6K + 0\Omega} = 0.00618375:1
$$
Assuming a reference of 2.5V, we get an output of:
$$
\frac{2.5V}{0.00618375} = 404.285V
$$

For the other extreme where the pot is 50k we get:
$$
\frac{5.6K + 50k\Omega}{3\times300k + 5.6K + 50k\Omega} = 0.05818334:1
$$
And we get an output of:
$$
\frac{2.5V}{0.05818334} = 42.968V
$$

The module is rated as going from 45 V to 390 V, so these numbers seem reasonable.

Let's see what happens if we swap the pot out for a 100k pot.
$$
\frac{5.6K + 100k\Omega}{3\times300k + 5.6K + 100k\Omega} = 0.10501193:1
$$
And we get an output of:
$$
\frac{2.5V}{0.10501193} = 23.807V
$$
So all this would do is lower the minimum output voltage, which may or may not be a safe thing to do.

If you only need the supply to work within a narrow range of voltage rather than the full 45 V to 390 V, you can use a lower value pot and increase the 5.6K fixed resistor, for example a 10k pot and 10k fixed will give you a range of roughly 115 V to 227 V. The higher the values the lower the limits, the fixed resistor affects both upper and lower limit, the pot value only affects the lower limit, so you would pick the fixed resistor to set the upper limit with the pot at zero, and the pot value to set the lower limit when it's at it's full resistance.